# Can I restore iMac's OS10.12 with DVD from Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootable-media, imac, intel-core-i3

Bought used July 2010 iMac 27 with OS 10.12, no restoration disc.  Ran ok for a couple weeks, but now it powers off halfway through startup.  Can I download OS 10.12 to DVD on my Windows 7 PC to boot iMac?  Both have Core i3.  Thank you.

Comment: "Powers off halfway through startup" tells me that there's a physical problem, possibly a cpu heatsink issue.  You may attempt to boot to external media (a Live ISO on a USB or DVD) to see if the poweroff happens with all OSes.

Comment: The literal answer to your question is probably yes, but you would need to get the Mac ISO from somewhere trustworthy.  The official way to do it from Apple requires a working Mac ... https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Comment: Reinstalling the OS won’t solve the problem you describe

Comment: At 7 years old, my first suspect would be the PRAM battery. Unfortunately on an iMac they are an absolute b@$†@®∂ to change. See https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2389+PRAM+Battery+Replacement/6292 The battery itself you can get from any supermarket for a buck these days, everything uses those CR2032's. If in any doubt, take it to a professional.

Comment: I swapped the PRAM battery, which tested 2.5 volts. No change.  I noticed that just before it shuts down, the fan sound increases. I found Apple Technician Guide, imac_27_mid10.pdf.  Will give that a try.  Thanks.